# Google Spectrum Database API missing from Cloud Console

Tags: google-api

I'm trying to set up a first-time project in the Google Spectrum Database API, but it's not showing as an option in the API list.

[I read these instructions](https://developers.google.com/spectrum/paws/gettingstarted), and did the following :

1. Go to the Google Cloud Console.
2. Select a project.
3. In the sidebar on the left, select APIs & auth.
4. In the displayed list of APIs, make sure the Google Spectrum Database API status is set to ON. **(Google Spectrum Database not showing)**

I'm simply trying to set up a project for testing purposes, not commercial.
Any thoughts or guidance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm with ya! I'm getting the same notice. It's just not listed there. Please update this with a solution if you find one. I'll do the same.

Answer (score 0):

This has just been updated. I asked what's up here: https://support.google.com/spectrumdatabase/contact/spectrum_feedback

and they replied with:

```
It may have not shown up earlier today, but please take another look. The "Google Spectrum Database API" should be visible in the (long) list of APIs by now.

If you have further questions, please ask in the the support group (https://groups.google.com/d/forum/google-spectrum-db-discuss) linked from the getting started page: https://developers.google.com/spectrum/paws/gettingstarted#questions

Sincerely,

The Google Spectrum Database Team
```

I checked and it is indeed there now. Hope this helps.